# HP Z440: Does downgrading a BIOS downgrading the CPU microcode as well

Tags: cpu, bios

I'm having a HP Z440 Workstation (E5-1680v4 and 128 GB RAM, BIOS 2.39 Rev.A) and I've a problem with the Profiler of Visual Studio 2013, see [Visual Studio 2013 Profiler chrashes and system restarts / reboots](https://superuser.com/questions/1287914/visual-studio-2013-profiler-chrashes-and-system-restarts-reboots).

Now I'm asking me if downgrading the BIOS from Version 2.39 to the previous 2.38 is downgrading as well the CPU microcode?

I saw that Intel has stopped the deployment, see https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/microcode-update-guidance.pdf

Comment: In theory, yes, but it might depend on the BIOS updater granularity. A BIOS update could in theory have several "modules" which are individually checked for versions and updated separately. Practically though this is a bit unlikely and a downgrade will downgrade the microcode as well. The only way to be sure is to try it.

Comment: Microcode is applied each time the system boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- BIOS V2.38 has CPU microcode version 0x1F
- BIOS V2.39 has CPU microcode version 0x25 (has been removed by HP)
- BIOS V2.41 has CPU microcode version 0x2A

Downgrading the BIOS version downgrades as well the CPU microcode version on my HP Z440.

Comment: Is there any chance of sharing details of how you detected microcode versions?

Comment: @Mokubai BIOS / Show System Information / Advanced System Information

Comment: HP has removed Version 2.39 from their Website, see https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05869091. HP will be reissuing HP BIOS softpaqs with previous Intel microcode starting January 25, 2018